# why this function not return any value?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to  Angular. I am trying to create a function for check user is logged in or not but function in onAuthStateChanged does not return any value

```
 async loginStatus() { 
     firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
      if ( firebaseUser) {
       console.log(firebaseUser.uid)
        this.isuser = true
    } else {
       this.isuser = false
    }
  })

return  this.isuser ;
}
```

> print loginStatus undefined

Comment: Thank you, I know that, but all of these solutions do not work for me, returning an unknown value . @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1):

If you are just checking once if there is a firebase user, you can (as Frank van Puffelen suggested) return this `.currentUser`. No need for promises:

```
loginStatus(): boolean {
  return !!firebase.auth().currentUser;
}
```

usage:

```
checkLoginStatus(): void {
  this.isuser = this.loginStatus();
}
```

---

If however you want to listen for user changes, you need to do this logic inside your method where you are attaching the listener:

```
loginStatus(): void {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => this.isuser = !!user);
}
```

With this the method does not return anything.

---

You can also think about using `Observables`, but then you might as well look at `@angular/fire`. A simple (untested) Observable would look like this:

```
readonly loginStatus$: Observable<boolean> = new Observable((subscriber) =>
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => subscriber.next(!!user))
).pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  startWith(!!firebase.auth().currentUser),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

<sub>As a side-note, by declaring the typings, you can tell the typescript compiler what you expect the method to return. If it does not comply, it will give you a descriptive error. Much easier to debug things :)</sub>

Comment: How is this code any different from simple returning `firebase.auth().currentUser`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen you are absolutely right :) I took it a bridge too far by returning it as a promise. If you are using a listener, the `onAuthStateChanged` listener should set the `isUser` part, and if you are just checking it once, you should check `.currentUser` like you said

Answer (score 0):

You **loginStatus** function dose not return anything. The return statement is inside your **onAuthStateChanged** callback. And you are returning an assignment expression which will be always true.

And based on the firebase document here

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth

**firebase.auth** is not an async function. You do not need await it.

In order to achieve a meaningful callback like

```js
const userObject = await loginStatus()
```

You need to return a Promise in loginStatus function like below

```js
async loginStatus() { 
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
     firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => resolve(firebaseUser))
  })
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why not just `resolve(!!firebaseUser)` rather than an `if/else`? `auth.onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => resolve(!!firebaseUser))`

Comment: @MatthewLayton I agree with u resolving the user object will be a better code structure. 

But I am not sure about his intention here. I am just trying to reuse his code structure as much as possible. He might want to add some logic in the if/else statement.

Comment: thanks but return object `auth[object Promise]` how exit value without function `this.checkLoginStatus().then((data)=>console.log(data))` because can't use value out function . @yueyou

Comment: This function only returns Promise<boolean> now, because I am trying to make it similar to your original function post. 

if you want to use the user object outside this function. Put the object in resolve like resolve(firebaseUser). Then this function will return a Promise<Object>

Comment: "+1" thanks ,  but return same value [object Promise] , I don't care about the value, I care about the type , need return value to use ```guard``` .  I near to depending on your answer . @yueyou

Comment: Do u mean u want a function called checkLoginStatus to have a signature like () => FirebaseUser? Remember to call await for this Promise function @AmeerAmjed

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/62408873/12212907 @yueyou

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the user's current login status, there's no need to attach a listener. You can just read `firebase.auth().currentUser`:

```
async loginStatus() { 
  return firebase.auth().currentUser != null
}
```

---

If you instead want a certain action to be performed **when** the user is logged in or out, you need an auth state listener. But in that case you can't return the user's state to the caller, and the code that takes the action should be inside the auth state listener.